# Quotes are not formatted correctly

Tags: fonts, luatex, unicode

Here is data about my problem that I consider relevant:

a) I'm using lualatex

b) Here is my prelude:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,twoside]{memoir} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Fanwood}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
...
```

c) And here is the latex input of one of the problematic fragments:

```
A not very precise answer to 
this question would be 
``a system for which the
predictive  power of current human rationality is limited''
```

Now, the problem is that there are no openning quotation marks in the output, I get something like this:

```
``a system for ... "
```

(there is a closing quotation mark with the correct glyph). The problem is somehow related to the font Fanwood; if I comment it everything works. But Fanwood has a glyph for open quotation marks at Unicode U+201C, I checked in "Character Map", a font and unicode inspector of Linux. So I suspect that there is something more...

Question: how do I get around this problem?

This of course could be the duplicate of some question, if so, please point it to me please! So far no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a flaw in Fanwood. To use ASCII notation for quotation marks and dashes with `fontspec`, add the feature `[Ligatures=TeX]`:  `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Fanwood}`.  See section 10.1 of the `fontspec` manual.

Comment: Thanks! It works this way. I read into the fontspec manual and I found that ligatures for opentype are controlled by a separate option.